# deoplete.nvimを使いたいですが、has('python')が1になりません

Tags: python, vim

自分の環境のVimでは :echo has('python3') は1なのですが、NeoVimは0です。どうやら$VIMRUNTIMEがおかしいのではないか(/usr/share/vim/vim73になっている)というところまではたどり着いたのですが、そこからがわかりません。

たぶんインストールが失敗しているので、[install from source](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#install-from-source)を見てやってみました。しかし、それでも$VIMRUNTIMEがおかしいままです。$VIMは/usr/local/share/nvimになりました。

pip3 install neovimでpythonのインターフェースはインストールできています。どのようにしたら :echo has('python3') が1になりdeoplete.nvimが使えるようになるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは。この問題は他の環境でも見ました。その人も Mac OS X でした。
原因がよく分かりませんが、ランタイムパスが neovim のものになることが原因です。

とりあえず、/usr/share/vim/vim73 に /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/ に対するシンボリックリンクを貼るか
init.vim の中で set rtp+=/usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/ とでもするしかないでしょうね。